# How to show just last 2 line in div or multiline with react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement streaming text service by react, and material-ui.
it needs to show just 2 lines from div or whatever.
Now I tried to trigger scrolling to bottom if text is updated,
but in this case I have some part of upper text is showing and
was hard to calculate line height with text size.

do you have any idea for this?

Comment: How about -> Height = 2 * lineHeight, overflow hidden, flex, align flex-end

Comment: @Khalt how can I calculate lineHeight by text size? do you have idea?